# Does Google Play Services pre-release versions to developers?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I might be spoiled having worked on iOS for so long, but does Google release Google Play Service beta versions for developers prior to releasing the full versions to the public?

I'm currently working on an SDK project, and would like to test out the latest Google Play Services versions as early as possible, preferably before the full Google Play Services updates are released, to ensure that the SDK maintains functionality with the latest and greatest.

Am I missing something in the documentation?  Is there a place where beta / test versions are announced before a full release?

Comment: Yes they do, the L-preview has been available for some time and can be implemented into your projects. I believe they are only supported on android studio but can be wrong.  What environment are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> does Google release Google Play Service beta versions for developers prior to releasing the full versions to the public?

No. They do the opposite -- they do not release the updated Play Services SDK until a preponderance of devices have been updated to be able to support it. If your app is using the new SDK, and it winds up on a device with an old Play Services Framework, part of your use of the SDK will involve prompting the user to upgrade their Play Services Framework.

They do an admirable job on backwards compatibility on the whole, so apps written using earlier versions of the Play Services SDK usually continue to work on devices with new versions of the Play Services Framework.

> Is there a place where beta / test versions are announced before a full release?

Announcements about general capabilities are sometimes made on [the Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/), such as [this post about the release of Play Services 6.5](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/11/google-play-services-65.html).

Comment: This is the answer I was worried about, but thank you for giving it!  It's unfortunate, as 6.5.* was actually the version that broke backwards compatibility for Location services (for us), though we weren't aware of it until release day.  I guess we'll just have to keep fast-follow releases in mind for future development cycles.

Comment: @Maixy: Out of curiosity, what broke? The `LocationClient` class was deprecated, but it should still have worked. And while I haven't been paying a ton of attention to it, I also haven't heard cries of anguish over location services breaking in general when 6.5 shipped to devices.

Comment: LocationClient itself seems to have been removed, so updates to the latest G.Play Services ended up in :  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient; 
when referencing the old LocationClient APIs.  Updates obviously fix this, but backwards compatibility is definitely lost. :(

Comment: @Maixy: But that's a class in the client library. That does not mean that apps, compiled against an older library, would stop working. The *API* definitely changes (and I apologize for thinking that `LocationClient` was still deprecated and not ouright removed). But the primary compatibility concern of Google appears to be with older apps, compiled against older client libraries, working on newer devices with newer Play Services Framework engines.